# Where can i find the XML schema (XSD-file) for the Glade markup language?

Tags: xml, xsd, markup, glade

As stated in the title, i'm looking for an XML schema (XSD-file) for the Glade markup language?

Wikipedia states that **Glade** is a schema based markup language ([list of schemas at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_Schemas#Graphical_User_Interfaces)). I tried to search the web, wikipedia and the glade website,but i couldn't find an XSD for Glade.

Thx,
Juve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing that will explicitly tie down the glade to an particular schema since it's all run-time based.

You may find the .defs files generated by PyGTK useful.  If you really need an XSD file, you should be able to create one from these files.

[This](http://svn.gnome.org/viewvc/pygtk/trunk/gtk/gtk-base-types.defs?view=markup) looks like the main one, there's more in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

http://svn.async.com.br/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/libglade/glade-2.0.dtd?view=markup

(The main version @ http://glade.gnome.org/glade-2.0.dtd doesn't seem to be working)

Answer (score 0):

Thx, this is a first start. I assume there is no document that is more explicit that this DTD? This DTD only specyfies what (global) tags can be used. Especially for the tag <widget> i would like a have constraints on the attribute "class" (as supported by XSD). The XSD should cover that there are only certain values for the <widgets'>  "class" attribute, like GtKTreeView, etc.